# Rewrite Pascal for do loop using while do loop

Tags: pascal

Please how do I rewrite the below FOR....DO loop into a WHILE...DO loop in Pascal programming

Below is the following code

```
Program Matmuli(input,output);

:

:

FOR i:=1 TO m DO

  FOR j:=1 TO p DO

     BEGIN
    
        C[i,j]:= 0.0;
        FOR k:=1 TO n DO
          C[i,j]:= C[i,j] + A[i,k] * B[k,j];

     END;
```

Comment: `for i := a to b do P(i)` is the same as `i := a; while i <= b do begin P(i); Inc(i); end`. Use that three times.

Comment: Thanks bro.. which is better to loop through what I have above and why do you feel the one you say is best..

Comment: The `for` loop is the better choice in this case because it (clearly) is less code (and so easier to see and interpret mentally, less room for typos etc.).

Comment: ...moreover, in some (all?) pascal implementation, the for limit is calculated only once, not at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is well defined in terms of a `while` loop, confer [ISO 7185 “Standard Pascal”](http://www.pascal-central.com/iso7185.html#6.8.3.9%20For-statements), quote:

> Apart from the restrictions imposed by these requirements, the for-statement
>
> ```
> for v := e1 to e2 do body
> ```
>
> shall be equivalent to
>
> ```
> begin
>   temp1 := e1;
>   temp2 := e2;
>   if temp1 <= temp2 then
>     begin
>       v := temp1;
>       body;
>       while v <> temp2 do
>         begin
>           v := succ(v);
>           body
>         end
>     end
> end
> ```
>
> […]
>
> where `temp1` and `temp2` denote auxiliary variables that the program does not otherwise contain, and that possess the type possessed by the variable `v` […]

The important thing from this *expanded* piece of code is, as [linuxfan says Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291271/rewrite-pascal-for-do-loop-using-while-do-loop#comment117361672_66291271) already noted, that *in* *Pascal* the limits of a `for` loop are only evaluated once. Furthermore, the *control-variable* is only assigned a value if there was *indeed* at least one iteration.

However, usually it’s sufficient to transform a `for` loop as [Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291271/rewrite-pascal-for-do-loop-using-while-do-loop#comment117198076_66291271) already suggested, although it is *technically* *not* the same.